# ATM Problem Code: HS08TEST codechef Question in C (What is Wrong with this code)

Tags: c

https://www.codechef.com/problems/HS08TEST

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) 
{
    int withdraw;
    float balance;
    float total_withdraw;
    scanf("%d %d",&withdraw,&balance);
    
    if(withdraw % 5 !=0)
    {
        printf("%0.2f",balance);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    if(withdraw > 2000 || withdraw==0)
    {
        printf("%0.2f",balance);
        exit(1);
    }
    
    total_withdraw= withdraw + 0.5;
    
    if(total_withdraw >= balance)
    {
        printf("%0.2f",balance);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%0.2f",balance - total_withdraw);
        
    return 0;
}
```

**what is wrong in this code, please help.it is the question from CodeChef**
Ques. Pooja would like to withdraw X $US from an ATM. The cash machine will only accept the transaction if X is a multiple of 5, and Pooja's account balance has enough cash to perform the withdrawal transaction (including bank charges). For each successful withdrawal the bank charges 0.50 $US. Calculate Pooja's account balance after an attempted transaction.

Comment: Use `%f` to read a float.

Comment: When asking a question it is recommended to also include a proper question, explain what you have tried and what your actual problem is.

Comment: Try out my answer. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Just like in the comments, you need `%f` to read floating-point values. Also, you need to use `<stdlib.h>` to actually use `exit()` properly.

So this should lead to something that looks like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    int withdraw;
    float balance;
    float total_withdraw;
    scanf("%d %f", &withdraw, &balance);

    if (withdraw % 5 !=0)
    {
        printf("%0.2f\n", balance);
        exit(1);
    }

    if (withdraw > 2000 || withdraw==0)
    {
        printf("%0.2f\n", balance);
        exit(1);
    }

    total_withdraw = withdraw + 0.5;

    if (total_withdraw >= balance)
    {
        printf("%0.2f\n", balance);
        exit(1);
    }

    printf("%0.2f\n", balance - total_withdraw);

    return 0;
}
```